# Fantasy novel where a woman (believing herself to be under threat) tells a man: "Keep back! Or I'll kill myself, and you too."

Tags: story-identification, novel, sword-and-sorcery

I'm remembering a scene in a fantasy novel where the main character, possibly a swordsman or warrior type, is travelling somewhere and comes across a woman on the road. Believing herself to be under threat, the woman pulls out a weapon (knife?) and threatens the man saying something like: "Keep back! Or I'll kill myself, and you too."

The hero is somewhat amused by this and responds that she'd better not try it in that order.

I'd say I read it sometime in the '90s, but I won't swear to that.

I think it was a Swords & Sorcery type story. Possibly a Conan one, though probably not by Howard. Or something by David Gemmell. There's an outside chance it could be by Michael Moorcock or even one of the Gor novels I inflicted on myself before I knew better.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[The King Beyond the Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_Beyond_the_Gate), one of the books in David Gemmell's Drenai saga. The character Tenaka is remembering his beloved wife Illae (now dead) whom he originally bought as a slave:

> Beautiful Illae, the bride he had purchased in a Ventrian market. He smiled at the memory. Two thousand pieces of silver and he had taken her home only to have her refuse to share his bed.
>
> 'Enough of this nonsense,' he had stormed. 'You are mine. Body and soul! I bought you!'
>
> 'What you bought was a carcass,' she retorted. 'Touch me and I will kill myself. And you too.'
>
> 'You will be disappointed if you try it in that order,' he said

Comment: How on Earth did you find this with so little to go on? Wow.

Comment: @AlexM In my younger days I loved Gemmell's books and bought everything he wrote the moment it appeared in the shops. Even in my cynical old age I still think [Legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_(Gemmell_novel)) is a masterpiece of heroic fantasy.

Comment: I'll put it on my list! Thanks

Comment: Excellent.  That's it, thank you.  Looks like I had some details wrong.